# Bug in gcc wstring_convert?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw, wstring

I use MinGW 8.1.0 64-bit. This code snippet:

```cpp
#include <clocale>
#if __has_include(<codecvt>)
#include <codecvt>
#endif
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto utf8_decode = [](const std::string &str) -> std::wstring {
      std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
      return myconv.from_bytes(str);
    };

    std::string test = "=";
    auto s = utf8_decode(test);

    std::wcout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

outputs a hieroglyphic (or some gibberish) on Windows, but outputs `=` (as expected) on Linux.
Is this a bug in standard library or am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds more like a "bug" in the environment... When you run on Windows are you using the old "command line" window (a.k.a. the "DOS prompt")? Because IIRC that doesn't handle Unicode very well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can actually see in the debugger that `s` points to gibberish; computing its length will also be incorrect, without actual output to stdout.

Comment: @Amomum Define "gibberish".  Because what you consider to be "gibberish" might just be an encoding you don't understand. What does the raw data actually look like? What is the actual size?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, on linux it looked just like `=` - and I suppose that it should always look like that because that symbol is part of ASCII and should be the same in utf8. Or is it?

Comment: Yes, `=` is encoded the same way in ASCII and UTF-8. But you doesn't answer my question - what "gibberish" are you actually seeing, and WHERE are you seeing it? In the debugger? In the terminal?

Comment: @Remy on windows I saw some kind of hieroglyphic, in the debugger.

Comment: Again, can you show the actual raw data you are seeing?

Comment: @RemyLebeau original string `test` is `0x32 0x00`. First element of wstring `s` is shown as `0x00003d00` or as `㴀`.

Comment: @Amomum "*original string `test` is `0x32 0x00`*" - then you already have corruption from the very beginning, because the `'='` character is `0x3D` in ASCII and UTF-8, not `0x32` (which is `'2'`). But `0x3d00` makes sense for `'='` in a `std::wstring` when `wchar_t` is 2 bytes (as it is on Windows). A single `wchar_t` can't be a 32bit value on Windows, as you have shown, so you are probably just looking at a 16bit value extended to 32bits.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry, 0x32 was a misprint. Okay, wchar_t indeed is 2 bytes wide but debugger for some reason shows it with too many leading zeros. Anyway, what doesn't imo make sense is that `=` in wchar_t gets interpreted as `0x3d00` and not `0x003d`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I also just checked that in Visual Studio and there it prints `=` in the same windows terminal with no problem; debugger shows that wstring is equal to `L"="` and in raw bytes view (although a bit complicated) it is shown as `0x003d`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/538/ this looks similar. I'm sorry that I couldn't phrase my question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is indeed [a bug in MinGW libstdc++.dll](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/538/); codecvt incorrectly chooses big endian so `=` (0x3d) becomes `㴀` (0x3d00).

Proposed workaround - manually force little-endian by using `codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>`